# Зачем MongoDB и memcached, если есть @lru_cashe / @cashe / @cached_property в модуле functools?

Tags: python, mongodb, кэширование, декоратор

Нужен "философский" ответ с небольшим примером, если понадобится. Видимо, я не все знаю о MongoDB. Его основное предназначение - как я понимаю - кеширование данных, чтобы избежать обращения к диску. Но эту же функцию выполняeт в Python декоратор ***@lru_cashe*** (Least recently used) модуля [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). Кроме того, есть еще и  @cashe - который хранит все, а не последние "вычисления" функции с заданными параметрами.

**Redis** - другое дело. Он хранит данные распределенно и все такое, а  **MongoDB** - насколько я знаю живет на одной машине или я ошибаюсь?

Да, знаю, можно было погуглить... Но приятно пообщаться с умными людьми...

Comment: Даже на одной машине это всё ещё лучше, чем в одном процессе.

Comment: ну минусите, минусите... Художника легко обидеть ))

Comment: Даже в википедии по монго написано, что она может реплицироватся на несколько узлов и так же из коробки доступен шардинг. А вообще это докуменоориентированная БД и специально не создавалась с целью кеширования. Она может использоваться для кеша но там надо отдельно колдовать что бы делать LRU ибо из коробки этого нет

Comment: @ну реплицироваться - это про безопасность как я понимаю. Хотя да, краснею. Прочел статью на Redis про Redis&MongoDB  https://redislabs.com/docs/why-your-mongodb-needs-redis/  ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первое на что надо ответить при выборе кеширования: требуется ли видеть одинаковое состояние объекта при наличии нескольких python процессов.

Да, я то же предпочитаю мелкие справочники держать в памяти процессов. И если один из процессов какое то время видит старую версию объекта я не переживаю.

Но есть большой пласт задач для которых такое поведение недопустимо, требуется своевременный сброс кеша и только самая свежая версия объекта. И без внешнего общего кеша тут уже ни как не обойтись. А что выбирать memcached, Redis или еще что то тут дело вкуса и опять же некоторых тонкостей решаемых задач. У memcached есть встроенный LRU. У Redis же только таймеры жизни записей и LRU очистку придется делать самому. Но у Redis гораздо более широкий функционал, мне доводилось использовать и счетчики и различные виды очередей.

Comment: "Ну зря вы гулить не хотите" :) В Redis тоже есть что-то похожее на LRU https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache (и это заодно поднимает вопрос, а нафиг вообще нужен memcached)

Comment: @andreymal Да, не знал. При беглом осмотре понял что он видимо глобально включается, мне бы такой режим не подошел, потому что есть объекты которые никогда не должны вытесняться.

Comment: Вот да, это проблема, я его тоже до сих пор не попробовал по той же причине

Answer (score 6):

Ну зря вы гуглить не хотите, `MongoDB` - это вообще-то полноценная документоориентированная БД.

И да, кэширующие декораторы - это хорошо, но они либо упираются в размер памяти (если это `@lru_cache`), либо всё-равно хранят и ищут данные не оптимально (если это декораторы, хранящие кэш в файлах). БД нужны для того, чтобы быстро искать по неким параметрам (и обновлять) определённые виды данных. Это совсем не тоже самое, что просто кэш объектов, задачи БД гораздо шире. Хотя некоторые БД бывает используют в качестве кэша.

Comment: да, я погуглил. Похоже MongoDB вообще не подходит для кеширования?
Это прерогатива Redis, да?
Это последний мой вопрос...
Мне нужно поднять пару десятков признаков в память из базы.
Для этого как я понял вполне достаточно просто @cashe. Да?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets На самом деле таких БД дофига, не только Redis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases

Comment: @VasylKolomiets от конкретной ситуации зависит что использовать. вот например статья по использованию монго в качестве кеша https://habr.com/ru/post/219481/

Comment: @Mike  -  я просто спутал `memcached` с MongoDB.  Ну не править же вопрос, когда уже пошли ответы...

Comment: @VasylKolomiets ну а в memcached смысл тоже есть - он общий для всех процессов, в отличие от lru_cache

Comment: @Mike - прошу оформите вашу реплику как ответ.
Это именно то, что мне было нужно.

Comment: Кэширование это вообще большая интересная тема, там нет прямо универсального подхода, который подошёл бы всем. Нужно смотреть конкретику